# Logic question about implication

Tags: logic

Given the logic rule: When the weather is stormy - The fish aren't sleep.

Why **can't** we deduce: When the fish sleep - The weather isn't stormy

But, we **can** deduce: When the fish aren't sleep - the Weather is stormy.

Comment: I want to understand why the first sentence can't be deduced, whereas the second sentence is logically true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "logical rules" are :

> from "if $P$, then $Q$" deduce : "if not $Q$, then not $P$

and :

> from "if $P$, then not $Q$" deduce : "if $Q$, then not $P$.

Thus, if we assume that :

> When the weather is stormy - The fish aren't sleep

has the same meaning of :

> If the weather is stormy, then the fish aren't sleep,

it has the "logical form" :

> "if $P$, then not $Q$.

Thus, from it we **can** deduce :

> If the fish sleep, then the weather is not stormy.

---

Instead, from "if $P$, then $Q$, we **cannot** deduce : "if $Q$, then $P$.

Comment: @amWhy, thank you sir!

Answer (score 3):

It's just the opposite. You can deduce the first sentence, but not the second one.

Do you still need an explanation?